# Are Kaons and Pions (mesons) made up of quarks?

Tags: quarks, mesons, pions

I have tried to reasearch this and google says yes.

But i learnt that pions decay into muons and netrinos (and the antiparticle versions) which are basically electrons and neutrinos

Which are fundamental particles!

So how are Pions and kaons made up of quarks

Comment: There is no law of conservation of quark number, or conservation of lepton number for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that kaons and pions are made up of quarks, however composite particles that are unstable do not necessarily decay into their constituent particles. The weak interaction is responsible for radioactive decay, and it can change particle flavor. The muon, for instance, decays into an electron and some neutrinos, however the muon is not made of electrons and neutrinos, it isn't really made of anything, but it decays into these particles due to weak interactions.

Comment: Thank you for this very concise and understandable answer. I do have a follow up-question though. When you say a muon is not really made up of anything is that beacuse it is a heavy electron and an electron is a fundamental particle so has no internal structure or is it because physics has not discovered what it is made of. Thanks

Comment: You're very welcome! To answer your question, a muon isn't made up of anything because, like the electron, the muon is an elementary particle, and so it can't be said to have any internal structure (i.e., something that makes it up). It may be that elementary particles really come from something else (like strings) but there is no experimental evidence for this.